# Display unicode in python without print

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to display unicode characters without using `print` for example  :

```
>>> print 'é'
é
```

The unicode is displayed perfectly but when I try to display without print it gives me unwanted results :

```
>>> 'é'
'\xc3\xa9'
```

And the expected result is `'é'`

**EDIT**

The reason why I need this feature is, I m writing a scraper with scrapy framework, and I m crawling a website with unicode charachters, when I start crawling the log display something like this :

```
\u06a9\u06cc\u0644\u0648 \u0645\u062a\u0631 \u0628\u0631 \u0633\u0627\u0639\u062a\r\n\r\n
```

I've tried to use `unicode` built-in function, and I've added the header

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But without any results

Comment: Can you show an example of why you need this to happen / what kind of program it would be going into?

Comment: I m trying to display unicode charachters in scrapy log

Comment: Looks like an xy problem. What you see here is only the repr of the last expr in interactive python before it displays the prompt. You do not need that (or should not because you will not get it :-) ). Give a real example where you see the repr of an UTF8 string when you would like the string itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3 could be your solution, this version supports UTF-8 as default string encoding.

Comment: this should be more of a comment

Comment: 36 rep users can't post comments, sadly

Comment: @KevinW. forgot that :P

Comment: @KevinW. not 36 rep for long! But really I think this is potentially the right answer to X in this particular problem that looks a lot like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, but `print` statement converts objects given certain string conversion rules. You're seeing the value through conversion.

The expression is the raw return when you're experiencing the unicode.

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt